# check confirmation script and do link to route action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a question on laravel 5 and I think It's simple 
I have "x" icon ; this icon is for delete item . there is a confirmation script which make the deletion of the item's div . but I want to implement the back-end action

the code now is fine for interface . it is :

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs remove" href=" javascript: jQuery('.item-{{$i}}').remove()" data-confirm="Are you sure" data-confirm-button="yes" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

and the link route I want to add is :

```
 {!! link_to_route('item_delete','', $id) !!}
```

How can I combine the back-end to the interface ? I mean combine the script confirmation with route action?

I appreciate any help

Comment: [This may help](http://heera.it/bootstrap-3-delete-confirm-dialog).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by AJAX. Since you need $i generated from php loop and url generated from laravel, then we cannot put these variables in javascript.

HTML.

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs remove" onclick="removeItem({{$i}},{!! link_to_route('item_delete','', $id) !!});" data-confirm="Are you sure" data-confirm-button="yes" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

Javascript.

```
function removeItem(i,url){
 $.post( url,  { _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' }, function( data ) {
    //check the data return from back-end and remove the x icon. assume return 0 is success.
     if(data===0){
        jQuery('.item-'+i).remove();
     }
 });
};
```

Please check syntax again, some maybe wrong :).

Comment: I tried this , the front-end is working good but seems like the link_to_route doesn't work .. I get beck to my page

Comment: I think i'm missing csrf_token in post data which need in laravel. Please try again. Anyway, what do you mean about the link_to_route doesn't work? Does link_to_route function generate the correct url for you? or is there some error in that url?